# Why is this span tag not updating with state?

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble updating a span with some text for how many credits each select option has associated with it. Im a bit of a noob with react and just need some help with how to manage state and such.
I using the Mern stack and need to keep typing to allow this to post

```
const CreditsPage = () => {

    const [plan, setPlan] = useState({ 
                                       value: '',
                                       label: '',
                                       credits: '' // bring in state
                                     })
    const planOptions = [{
        value: '10',
        label: '$10', // options values to map over
        credits: '250'
    }, {
        value: '20',
        label: '$20',
        credits: '550'
    }, {
        value: '50',
        label: '$50',
        credits: '1350'
    }]
    return (
    <CustomInput
          type="select"
          id="plan"
          name="plan"
          className="mb-3"
          value={plan}
          onChange={({ target }) => setPlan(target.value)}
        >
            {planOptions.map((plans) => (<option value={plans.value}>{plans.label}</option>))}
        </CustomInput>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between text-success fs--1 mb-1">
          <p className="mb-0"></p>
          <span>{plan.credits</span> // why isnt this showing the credits?
          {console.log(plan.credits)}
        </div>
```

Comment: Your plan state is initiated with an object. But in onChange you set it as string. So in span, plan.credits will be undefined

Comment: how can I use the onChange to update the state with each new value, label, and credits?

Comment: @AmandaConda please add the code of CustomInput component

Comment: You're missing a closing curly brace as well.. "{plan.credits"

Comment: its the CustomInput from 'reactstrap'

Comment: @AmandaConda Does that target.value consists of plan object as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a library called react-select

Here is what I changed my select to look like

````
 const [plan, setPlan] = useState({  amount: 2000,
                                        value: "20",
                                        label: "$20",
                                         credits: "550"})
    const planOptions = [{
        amount: 1000,
        value: "10",
        label: "$10",
        credits: "250"
    }, {
        amount: 2000,
        value: "20",
        label: "$20",
        credits: "550"
    }]


// now in your component under the return use the Select like below
 <Select
        styles={customStyles}
        className="mb-3"
        onChange={setPlan} <-- this onChange updates every plan.prop
        options={planOptions}
        default
        >
        </Select>


  // now I can access every plan.label, plan.credits, or plan.value in different divs or whatever I want. It updates in realtime so it looks cool
   <div className="d-flex justify-content-between text-success fs-1 mb-1">
          <p className="mb-0"></p>
          <span> {plan.label} to Potentially Reach  {plan.credits} People</span>
         
        </div>```
````